# Passing a subclass of a class that inherits from ctypes.Structure

Tags: python, ctypes

For code-cleanliness, I want to have my auto-generated ctypes wrapper for my c-structure separate from my Python-only extension (which has additional helper functions, etc).

I having trouble passing my sub-classed structure to the bindings that I auto-generated. Is there a way to do this?

```
// C Code
typedef struct CStruct
{
    int value;
} CStruct;

int CFunc(const CStruct **pCStruct);
```

Auto-generated python bindings:

```
# Python Implementation
import ctypes
class PyStruct(ctypes.Structure)
    _fields_ = ['value', ctypes.c_int32]

pyfunc = dll.CFunc
pyfunc.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(PyStruct)),)
pyfunc.restype = ctypes.c_int32
```

Create a subclass from my bindings, and try to pass to my func:

```
class PySubStruct(PyStruct):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PySubStruct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def value_mult(self, factor):
        return self.value * factor

# Works great
structptr = ctypes.pointer(PyStruct())
result_A = pyfunc(ctypes.byref(structptr))

# Create an instance of substruct and call the c-func.
# Raises exception
substructptr = ctypes.pointer(PySubStruct())
result_B = pyfunc(ctypes.byref(substructptr))
```

Here is the exception:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:
    expected LP_LP_PyStruct instance instead of 
    pointer to LP_PySubStruct
```

Is there a way to do this without modifying the auto-generated bindings or "monkey-patching"?

Comment: Looks like `ctypes` is just that "C types".  It doesn't know about subclassing.  `ctypes.cast` would probably help.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I took a look at ctypes.cast not long after I posted. Unfortunately, the docs and examples seemed pretty scarce. I kept getting various TypeErrors. If you have  a clean example of how to use cast in the context above, that would be super helpful. At the moment, I'm just creating a whole parallel class that consumes the ctypes.Structure as an argument and just interfaces on top of it, instead of extending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments, here's an example using `ctypes.cast`:

```
# Python Implementation
import ctypes
class PyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('value', ctypes.c_int32)]

# Declaring a type name for simplicity
LP_LP_PyStruct = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(PyStruct))

pyfunc = ctypes.CDLL('x').CFunc
pyfunc.argtypes = (LP_LP_PyStruct,) # Using the typename
pyfunc.restype = ctypes.c_int32

class PySubStruct(PyStruct):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PySubStruct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def value_mult(self, factor):
        return self.value * factor

# Works great
structptr = ctypes.pointer(PyStruct())
result_A = pyfunc(ctypes.byref(structptr))

# Create an instance of substruct and call the c-func.
# Now works great
substructptr = ctypes.pointer(PySubStruct())
result_B = pyfunc(ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(substructptr),LP_LP_PyStruct))
```